Question about the property $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ if and only if either $c - \delta < x < c$ or $c < x < c + \delta$
I saw in a proof that used this property of absolute values:

$0 < |x - c| < \delta$ if and only if either $c - \delta < x < c$ or $c < x < c + \delta.$

And I am confused why the inequality 0 < |x - c| < δ remains true if c - δ < x < c is false or or c < x < c + δ is false. For reference, I included the link to the proof that mentioned this property.

Let’s simplify this. If $x\ne 0$, then either $x>0$ or $x<0$. These cannot occur simultaneously, right?

Welcome to Math SE. Note $0 \lt \lvert x-c\rvert\lt\delta$ means that $-\delta\lt x-c\lt 0$ or $0\lt x-c\lt \delta$.

If only one of them is false, (let's say it's $c-\delta <x<c$), then the other one is still true, that is, $c<x<c+\delta$, which implies $0<x-c<\delta$ (since $c<x$, this is equivalent to $0<|x-c|<\delta$). If $0<|x-c|<\delta$, can both of them be false? (Hint: John Omielan's comment).

I don't get the question. The problem in the question is the ".... is false or ... is false."


To prove:


$0 < |x - c| < \delta$ if and only if either $c - \delta < x < c$ or $c < x < c + \delta.$

This (true conjecture) may be routinely proven without any regard for limits, simply by examining case work.
Either Case 1: $~x \geq c,~$ or Case 2: $~x < c.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~x \geq c}$
Then, $~|x - c| = (x - c).~$
Since you are given that $~0 < |x - c|,~$ the possibility of $~x = c~$ must be excluded.
Therefore, within Case 1, you can conclude that $~c < x,~$ and that $~x - c < \delta.~$
Further, you have that
$$[ ~x - c < \delta ~] \iff [ ~x < c + \delta ~].$$
Putting this all together, inside of Case 1, you have that
$$[ ~c < x ~] ~~\text{and} ~~[ ~x < c + \delta ~].$$
The above assertion is exactly equivalent to the assertion that
$$c < x < c + \delta. \tag1 $$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~x < c}$
Then, $~|x - c| = (c - x).~$
Therefore, within Case 2, you can conclude that $~x < c,~$ and that $~c - x < \delta.~$
Further, you have that
$$[ ~c - x < \delta ~] \iff [ ~c - \delta < x ~].$$
Putting this all together, inside of Case 2, you have that
$$[ ~x < c ~] ~~\text{and} ~~[ ~c - \delta < x ~].$$
The above assertion is exactly equivalent to the assertion that
$$c - \delta < x < c. \tag2 $$

So, either Case 1 is true, or Case 2 is true.
Therefore, either the assertion in (1) above is true, or the assertion in (2) above is true.
So, what has been proven so far is that
$$[ ~0 < |x - c| < \delta ~] ~~\text{implies}$$
that either the assertion in (1) above is true or the assertion in (2) above is true.

Now, it remains to prove that if:
either the assertion in (1) above is true or the assertion in (2) above is true
then the assertion that $~[ ~0 < |x - c| < \delta ~]~$ must be true.
If the assertion in (1) above is true, then
$|x - c| = (x - c), ~$ which implies that $~|x - c| < \delta.~$
Further, you also have that $~c < x \implies [ ~0 < (x - c) ~] \implies [ ~0 < |x - c| ~].$
Therefore, if the assertion in (1) is true,
then the assertion that $~[ ~0 < |x - c| < \delta ~] ~$ must also be true.
Suppose the assertion in (2) is true.
Then, $~x < c,~$ which implies that $[ ~|x - c| = (c - x)~], ~$ which implies that

$~0 < |x - c|.$

$~|x - c| = (c - x) < \delta.$


Therefore, if assertion (2) is true, then $~[ ~0 < |x - c| < \delta ~]~$ must also be true.
Therefore, if either assertion (1) is true, or assertion (2) is true,
then $~[ ~0 < |x - c| < \delta ~]~$ must also be true.

Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I should have clarified that the statement came from a proof that was about limits, the link is the proof that contains the statement.

@SarahAnderson I am going to leave my answer as is, since it was based on your originally posted problem.  I don't feel that MathSE answerers should have to hit a moving target, and my answer responds to the originally posted conjecture.  Going forward with your future MathSE questions, please try to clarify up front if (for example) you are looking for certain a type of analysis.

There's no need to change your answer at all, I'm sorry there must have been a misunderstanding. you mentioned in your answer that the proof doesn't need limits, and you're right. The only reason I mentioned limits was because the conjecture proven was originally part of a proof about limits. Your answer was detailed and helpful, thank you.

This is the definition of a $\delta$ neighborhood of $c$, not including $c$.
i.e. a deleted neighborhood of $c$.
It is necessary in the proof of existence of limits when $f(x)$ is not defined on $c$.
Example:
Prove that:
$\lim_{x->1} \frac{x-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}$
If $x=1$
We obtain $\frac{"0"}{"0"}$ which is undefined.
Let $\epsilon>0$ then there exists a $\delta>0, \delta=\min\{1, 2\epsilon\}$
s.t. for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-1|<\delta$
$|\frac{x-1}{(x^2-1)}-\frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2}|$
Since $0<|x-1|<\delta$,
$x\neq 1$
and $x-1$ term is cancelled thus we obtain:
$|\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{2-(x+1)}{2(x+1)}|=|\frac{x-1}{2(x+1)}|$
Now $0<|x-1|<\delta$
Implying
$1-\delta<x<1+\delta$
So for $\delta\leq 1\implies 0<x<1 \lor x>1$
Thus:
$|\frac{x-1}{2(x+1)}|<\frac{1}{2}|x-1|<\frac{1}{2}\delta=\epsilon$
Thus:
$\delta=\min\{1, 2\epsilon\}$

$\Rightarrow$)Suppose $0 < \vert x - c \vert < \delta$. Then $ - \delta < x - c < \delta$, wich implies $c - \delta < x < c + \delta$. Due to $c - \delta < c < c + \delta$, we have $c - \delta < x < c$ or $c < x < c + \delta$ because $0 < \vert x-c\vert$ by hypothesis (wich means $x \neq c$).
$\Leftarrow$)
Suppose $c - \delta < x < c$. Then $c - \delta < x < c + \delta$, and $- \delta < x - c < \delta$. Hence $0 < \vert x-c \vert < \delta$ because $x<c$. Now suppose $c < x < c + \delta$. Then $c - \delta < x < c + \delta$, and $- \delta < x - c < \delta$. Hence $0 < \vert x-c \vert < \delta$ because $c < x$.
